# NVIDIA GT430 HDMI/HDTV - No input after selecting Ubuntu from Grub

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, hdmi

I likely formatted the title horribly, but this is my issue; I'm using an NVIDIA GT430 with an HDMI cable to my TV, and when I try to boot up Ubuntu (12.10) after just installing it, It will not display anything, i.e. "No input." I can run the other options from the Grub and Windows 7 works from it, and I have it on two hard drives: Windows 7 is installed on **C:** or **/dev/sdb**, and Ubuntu is installed on **/dev/sda**, and they're both two different drives. I know that it needs drivers, of course, but I'm not sure if I can install them using a command line, is there any way to do that? If so, can anyone help me out with the commands I'd need, since I am completely new to Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `nvidia-current` driver in the TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>) , then do `sudo nvidia-xconfig` and reboot.